# getting Null EntityManager using @PersistenceContext

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:database="MYSQL" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"
            p:showSql="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="streamJpaDB" />
</bean>
```

persistance unit

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="streamJpaDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc.streamDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show-sql" value="true" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: does your jndi data source is configured properly? and does the entityManagerFactory can retrieve it without error?

Comment: <Resource name="jdbc/streamDataSource" global="jdbc.streamDataSource" auth="Container"  type="javax.sql.DataSource"  maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" 
  maxWait="10000" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scms" username="scms"  password="deepDb17"/>





</Context>

Answer (score 0):

- your non-jta-data-source should have the exact name of resource which is jdbc/streamDataSource
- if your container is tomcat you should add
       `<ResourceLink name="jdbc/streamDataSource"
         global="jdbc/streamDataSource"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>`
  to con/context.xml